# How to implement implicit conversion in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

For example, any type `T` can implicitly cast to function parameter `UnsafePointer<T>`. Is this a hack in Swift compiler? Can I implement it by my self?

```swift
struct A {
    // do something, allow A to implicitly convert to B
}

func readB(b: B) { ... }

readB(A) // Ok
```

Actually I'm reading something about `UnsafePointer`, Swift allows implicit pointer casting or bridging when calling functions that take pointers as parameters. I just want to find out how Swift supports this feature.

Comment: "any type T can implicitly cast to `UnsafePointer<T>`" That's not true... Can you show what you mean by that?

Comment: Regardless, implicit type conversion is very much against the design goals of Swift. It makes a few exceptions here and there (`ExpressibleByXXXLiteral` etc) where they think it will cause more good than harm. But allowing programmers to arbitrarily define implicit conversions? That opens up a whole other can of worms.

Comment: explain what You want to do. Usually You need some protocol. A will conform this protocol. And readB will be generic function where T: YourProtocol

Comment: @Sweeper `ExpressibleByXXXLiteral` does not use implicit conversion; if it did, you could use something other than literals with it.

Comment: @Jessy I don’t agree with “if it did, you could use something other than literals with it”. There is no implication here. “Implicit conversion” in my comment refers to something a lot more general than what you interpreted it meant. Why can’t I have an implicit conversion that only works on literals?

Comment: @Sweeper I means function parameter `UnsafePointer<T>` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters)

Comment: @Sweeper Because that's not semantically a conversion. A literal is not a type instance; it only looks like one, and acts like one at compile-time. A *conversion* necessitates runtime support. e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot implement [implicit casting or bridging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management/calling_functions_with_pointer_parameters) yourself.

The cleanest, and idiomatic, solution, is to implement type conversion as an initializer.

```swift
extension B {
  init(_ a: A) {
    // Convert.
  }
}

readB(
  b: .init(A())
)
```

Comment: So has the Swift compiler hard-coded so many implicit conversions into the compiler?

Comment: I think you're asking if there are a ton of these in the standard library? If so, yes.

Comment: My question is that if the implicit conversion can be implemented in the standard library (rather than hard-coded into the compiler), then I should be able to implement it myself (Because the standard library and my own code should be of similar status). But in fact, I can’t do this, and I haven’t found it in the standard library. If it is neither implemented in the standard library nor hard-coded into the compiler. How does Swift know when to allow conversion?

Comment: I can only think of three types of implicit conversion: 1. What we’ve gone over here, with `&`. 2. Everything can be cast to `AnyHashable`. 3. Objective-C bridging on Apple’s platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do someting like this

To use [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) You need to apply the methods based on common protocols

Example

```
protocol AB{
    var name: String {get set}
}

struct A: AB {
    var name: String = "A name"
}

struct B: AB {
    var name: String = "B name"
}

    
func readB<T: AB>(_ b: T) {
    print(b.name)
}

readB(A()) // "A name"
readB(B()) // "B name"
```

Comment: Actually I'm reading something about `UnsafePointer`, Swift allows implicit pointer casting or bridging when calling functions that takes pointers as parameters. I just want to find out how Swift supports this feature.

Comment: If you use class the variable passes to the function by refference you don't need to pass ponters etc. If you use structs the variabe is being passed by Value.